# AutoCAD using ObjectARX check Active (wait for) commands complete then Run Next Command With VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, command, wait, autocad

I had a problem with VB.NET or C # programming. For example, I have a loop containing drawing 1000 lines in AutoCAD. In other words, the new command is executed after the completion of the previous command. Wait for the new drawing to finish the previous drawing Without using sleep My goal is how to check the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
object obj = Application.GetSystemVariable("CMDNAMES");
```

and check if `obj` contains name of evaluated command

Comment: Thank you. But my problem was not solved .. I have an object that I draw first, then I call it so that the complete object is not drawn, I can not continue and it gives an error.
A program written with .NET is an external program that draws objects very slowly in AutoCAD and gives the following error.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))'

Comment: You asked the question: How to check if command is complete? . So this is my answer. It this not solve the problem, find better question.
In the code I see, that You are not drawing using commands but by objective model. That's OK, but I don't see the problem. And don't have free time to analyse your code and wonder where it may cause any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maybe I could not ask my questions well. For example, I want to draw an object, then mirror the object and then copy it. This operation is done with a thread, but because I use VB.net program, the commands are executed in order. If the system is slow, then the shape is not drawn, but the next line wants to be copied.

Comment: I am using ObjectARX

Comment: It's not a forum, where You ask the question, then change Your mind. This is questions and answers system. 

One thread, one question.

Comment: Please start with this
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED` because AutoCAD is busy and can not process your call. You have to implement the [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imessagefilter) interface in order to handle the rejection of your call.

This is explained here: https://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2010/02/handling-com-calls-rejected-by-autocad-from-an-external-net-application.html